# Ак-Кая, гора в Крыму. Склонение!Без родового слова!

Tags: склонение, топонимика

«На вершине великолепной Ак-Кая (есть ли склонение?)»

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Можно написать: *На вершине великолепной **Ак-Кая**...*

Здесь женский род имени собственного обозначен определением. В других же случаях топоним может восприниматься как Ак-Кай, что нежелательно. В то же время в текстах встречаются варианты написания: Ак-Кая, Ак-Каи.

2. Правило:  **Как склонять иноязычные географические названия?**

Названия, оканчивающиеся на -а

Испытывают **колебания** при склонении абхазские и грузинские топонимы, оканчивающиеся на безударное -а. Тем не менее многие из подобных названий склоняются: Очамчира – в Очамчире, Гудаута – до Гудауты, Пицунда – из Пицунды;   http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters?id=73

3. **Примеры:**

Вообще, на территории **Ак-Каи** найдено множество и других поселений древних людей.

А на самой вершине **Ак-Кая** открываются великолепнейшие виды.